# Query to get kWh from every minute watts readings

Tags: sql, mysql

I’m trying to get the amount of `kWh` consumed by my smart plug, my database is MySQL, I’m sending to my zabbix server (which uses MySQLdatabase) the power consumption in watts every minute.

ex:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(clock) as ts, value FROM history WHERE itemid=54339
```

```
2024-03-17 21:36:40 261
2024-03-17 21:37:39 271
2024-03-17 21:38:40 271
2024-03-17 21:39:40 268
2024-03-17 21:40:39 264
```

So if i wanted to calculate the kWh

- consumption per hour
- consumption per day
- consumption per month
- consumption per year

How could i achieve this with MySQL queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumption per hour:

```
SELECT 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(clock / 3600) * 3600) AS hour_start,
    SUM(value) / 1000 / 60 / 60 AS kWh_consumption
FROM 
    history 
WHERE 
    itemid = 54339
GROUP BY 
    hour_start
```

Per month you will have to concat year and month or select in separated columns:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(clock)), '-', LPAD(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(clock)), 2, '0')) AS month_year,
    SUM(value) / 1000 / 60 / 60 AS kWh_consumption
FROM 
    history 
WHERE 
    itemid = 54339
GROUP BY 
    month_year
```

Comment: It would be more accurate to use `LAG` to get the diff in seconds to the last reading, as they are not exactly one minute apart.

Answer (score 0):

Totals by several periods  WITH ROLLUP.

See example

```
select coalesce(yy,'total') yy
  ,case when yy is null then '--'
   else coalesce(mm,'tot yr')
   end mm
  ,case when mm is null then '--' 
   else coalesce(dt,'tot mnth') 
   end dt
  ,case when dt is null then '--'
   else coalesce(hh,'tot dy') 
   end hh
  ,cons
from(
select year(clock) yy
   ,month(clock) mm,date(clock)dt,hour(clock) hh,sum(val) cons
from history
group by year(clock),month(clock),date(clock),hour(clock) with rollup
)t
```

Output like this

| yy | mm | dt | hh | cons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024 | 3 | 2024-03-17 | 21 | 1071 |
| 2024 | 3 | 2024-03-17 | 22 | 535 |
| 2024 | 3 | 2024-03-17 | 23 | 532 |
| 2024 | 3 | 2024-03-17 | tot dy | 2138 |
| 2024 | 3 | 2024-03-18 | 21 | 264 |
| 2024 | 3 | 2024-03-18 | 23 | 264 |
| 2024 | 3 | 2024-03-18 | tot dy | 528 |
| 2024 | 3 | tot mnth | -- | 2666 |
| 2024 | 4 | 2024-04-01 | 7 | 264 |
| 2024 | 4 | 2024-04-01 | tot dy | 264 |
| 2024 | 4 | tot mnth | -- | 264 |
| 2024 | tot yr | -- | -- | 2930 |
| 2025 | 4 | 2025-04-01 | 7 | 101 |
| 2025 | 4 | 2025-04-01 | tot dy | 101 |
| 2025 | 4 | tot mnth | -- | 101 |
| 2025 | tot yr | -- | -- | 101 |
| total | -- | -- | -- | 3031 |

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QRvPyB6m)